# how to look for a specific word in browser-history

Tags: python, browser-history

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to search for a word or phrase using the python module browser-history. I am using the documented method on how to retrieve the history from chrome, and I have it printing to the console. Here is the code

```
from browser_history.browsers import Chrome

f = Chrome()
outputs = f.fetch_history()

# his is a list of (datetime.datetime, url) tuples
his = outputs.histories

histories = {}
print(outputs.histories)

if " google " in histories:
    print("L")
```

I am not really sure what I am doing with the histories or the if google in, but I am using knowledge from other projects. I don't know if the fact the data is coming from a SQL database is affecting it, but it shouldn't be. Hoping its just an easy fix that I am overlooking.

Comment: You are setting `histories = {}`, you should set `histories = outputs.histories`

Comment: @AmourK doing so  still does not give an output of true, even if I am looking at google.com showing up in the printed history output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

outputs.histories give you a list ([]) of  history data. A data (stored as a tuple) inside the list is like `(datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 31, 19, 38, 38, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=21600), 'Bangladesh Standard Time')), 'https://www.google.com/')` which is why only the term 'google' is not enough, you need `'https://www.google.com/'` for it to function.
You can just use a for loop to iterate through the list and find it, but if you don't want to put the full url, just turn those tuples into a string using:

```
from browser_history.browsers import Firefox

f = Firefox()
outputs = f.fetch_history()

if 'google' in str(outputs.histories):
    print(True)
```

And if you just want to find all the data with the term 'google' just do:

````
from browser_history.browsers import Firefox

f = Firefox()
outputs = f.fetch_history()


for his in outputs.histories:
    if 'google' in his[1]:
        print(his)```
````